# Android, How to fit an image into screen?

Tags: android, image, screen

I need to reduce the size of apk file which currently is 40M. This size is because of some high quality images. therefore, i decided to transfer these images to server and load them from there.

I created some html webpages and put each image in its own web page. In app, i used webview to open that link and show the images. However, images are bigger than screen size. previous time because i used image view, i could fit it to screen but now, i'm not sure is it possible to bound web page into screen size.

If you know, please guide me. Thanks

Comment: I dont know about web page..but there are other solutions too like move image to server and parse it runtime,or at first time parse all image and store in sdcard then use..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use ImageView?

Just create a drawable from stream and use it in your ImageView.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString); //urlString - url of your image
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "image");

imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```